# Electron desktop application is attempting a TCP connection when it should be an offline application

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, electron-builder

I have a Windows client application that was built using electron.  I have not configured any autoUpdate features and there are no webservices or need for networking.  The application is intended to be a standalone desktop application. However, I am noticing tcp connection attempts from the built executable to an random ip address being caught by my firewall.  When I look up the IP address it is some amazon hosted server.

Is there a setting in electron to force it and any dependencies to be a stand-alone application? Is there a way to track down what is attempting this connection? Am I overlooking something?

The commands that I use to build:

> **npm install**
> **npm install --global --production windows-build-tools**
>
> **npm run build**

Below is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Project Team",
  "description": "Stand-alone Application",
  "license": null,
  "main": "./dist/electron/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder",
    "build:dir": "node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder --dir",
    "build:clean": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=clean node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:web": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=web node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "dev": "node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",
    "watch": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=web node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",
    "e2e": "npm run pack && mocha test/e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue -f ./node_modules/eslint-friendly-formatter src test",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --ext .js,.vue -f ./node_modules/eslint-friendly-formatter --fix src test",
    "pack": "npm run pack:main && npm run pack:renderer",
    "pack:main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.main.config.js",
    "pack:renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.renderer.config.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "unit": "karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "build": {
    "productName": "project",
    "appId": "com.project",
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "include": "installer/installer.nsh",
      "createDesktopShortcut": "always",
      "oneClick": false,
      "runAfterFinish": false,
      "guid": "project"
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/electron/**/*"
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        },
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "file"
        }
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "icon": "build/icons/icon.icns"
    },
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/icons/Project3_256.png"
    },
    "linux": {
      "icon": "build/icons"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "dialogs": "^1.1.20",
    "jsonfile": "^5.0.0",
    "libxmljs": "^0.19.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "luxon": "^1.10.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "node-cmd": "^3.0.0",
    "really-relaxed-json": "^0.2.24",
    "regedit": "^3.0.2",
    "relaxed-json": "^1.0.1",
    "sqlite3-offline": "^4.0.6",
    "username": "^4.0.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-electron": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-router": "^2.8.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.3.5",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "babili-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
    "cfonts": "^1.1.3",
    "chai": "^4.0.0",
    "chalk": "^2.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^1.7.5",
    "electron-builder": "^20.38.4",
    "electron-debug": "^1.4.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-electron": "^5.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "multispinner": "^0.2.1",
    "node-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "spectron": "^3.7.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Does anything show in the network tab of the developer tools? If so, it should give a file and line number of the initiator.

Comment: @AlexWayne No, nothing is showing there.  These event only appear to happen every couple hours or when the network connection is toggled.